# How to tell which #include provides what object?

Tags: c++, c, include

Is there a way to tell where `Foo` comes from, without grepping every `#include`?

```
#include "Baz.h"
#include "Quuz.h"

int main() {
  Foo n;
}
```

Comment: Depends on your IDE. Or read the documentation

Comment: Consider using [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) instead of `grep`. And you also have [ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags). And [cedet](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/index.php) for `emacs`, etc.

Comment: Also, `Foo` can be a macro, or even obtained and declared by macro-expansion (see [X-macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)..).. So there are no general fool-proof solutions....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way is also the stupidest way: to define it again and get the error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int cout; //<--- just for test

int main(){
  cout<<"Hi!"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now when compiling (using gcc) I've got the errors:

```
 tt.cpp:8: error: reference to ‘cout’ is ambiguous 
 tt.cpp:5: error: candidates are: typedef int cout
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:59: error: std::ostream std::cout
```

Comment: Not portable, but terrific!

Comment: Accepting this... by virtue of the fact that I'll remember this technique for the rest of my life.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Preprocess the source without compiling it.  With GCC or Clang this means replacing `-c` with `-E` when "compiling" (and perhaps changing the output filename passed to `-o`.  Then you will have a complete expanded file with all #includes noted, and can grep that one file and see where Foo comes from.

Comment: ... Which might be a file included multiple times, with different intermediaries. Still, only the documentation gives the include-files which are part of the libraries interface, as well as which ones are contractually providing that symbol, and not only by happenstance for now.

Comment: Best to get a decent IDE and that should sort it out a lot easier. Visual Studio with VAssist is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/):

Build the tags:

```
$ cscope -R
```

Then choose:

```
Find this global definition: Foo
```

It will show you in which file(s) `Foo` is defined.